# Laravel image not downloading in the browser

Tags: php, laravel, image, browser, download

what is wrong with my code?
when I watch the preview in inspect element in the browser, I can see the image in the preview section. but the image is not downloading.

```
    $name = $result['name'];
    $path = $result['path'];
    
    $disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $name,
        str_replace('%', '', Str::ascii($name)));

    return \Response::download($path, $name, [
        'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
        'Content-Disposition' => $disposition
    ]);
```

browser response headers are here

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: public
Connection: close
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=e7853e60982911eb912b2192bf4aa5360341.png
Content-Length: 5095
Content-Type: image/png
```

[image: this is the sample image response in web browser]

Comment: Did you trigger this with a normal request, or is AJAX/fetch involved?

Comment: normal request. I tried also ajax. But nothing